# Parsing out information from a LinkedIn profile using VB Script

Tags: parsing, vbscript, linkedin-api, profile

Does anyone have an example that parses out the information from a LinkedIn profile using VBScript?  I have a database which contains client information, and I have been including the client Key for LinkedIn in hopes of having it automatically update some or possibly all of the information for that client.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you want out of there, but you'll want to use the Microsoft XMLHTTP request object.  My syntax may be a little rusty, and you should add error handling, but that looks roughly like this (complete reference easy to find on Google):

```
dim url, contents
dim xmlhttp_o
set xmlhttp_o = createobject( "microsoft.xmlhttp" )

'* generate complete url with the keys in your db *'
url = "http://linkedin.com/<whatever...>"

xmlhttp_o.open "get", url, false
xmlhttp_o.send

contents = xmlhttp_o.responsetext
```

At that point, `contents` contains the HTML of the page you want on LinkedIn.  A little string manipulation can get out whatever you want.